# Working with Oracle PL/SQL collections

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql

The goal I need to achieve is to get all records from a cursor into a collection to populate a table with data from that cursor.
Unfortunately I can't get to understand how to fetch data from the cursor into an array. 
I've tried with bulk collects but there is no way. 
What does the extend keyword mean?

And finally how to I get the data from that array?

I began by declaring a record with the needed fields. Then, I created a table of that type. Then I bulk collected everything from the cursor to the table. It seems to work but now how do I get the data from that table?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to select the data into an array to put it into a table? You can insert the results of a cursor directly into a table, ideally using the insert into ... select from ... syntax, which will be much faster and no arrays are required.

Comment: I agree with Stephen ODonnell, directly insert the rows using SQL as it's more efficient than using a PL/SQL cursor. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2145081

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you're having trouble with bulk collect: it's pretty straightforward.   It becomes slightly more difficult when we're dealing with tens of thousands of records, but you don't say whether that's a factor here.  Either way, you don't need to use extend with bulk collect.

```
SQL> SQL> SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2      type r_tmp is record
  3          ( empno number
  4            , deptno number
  5            , sal number );
  6      type nt_emp is table of r_tmp;
  7      emp_recs nt_emp;
  8  begin
  9      select e.empno
 10             , e.deptno
 11             , e.sal
 12      bulk collect into emp_recs
 13      from emp e;
 14      dbms_output.put_line('no of recs selected = '||emp_recs.count );
 15      forall i in emp_recs.first..emp_recs.last
 16          insert into temp_emp
 17          values emp_recs(i);
 18      dbms_output.put_line('no of recs inserted = '||sql%rowcount );
 19* end;
 20  /
no of recs selected = 17
no of recs inserted = 17

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

As you can see, inserting records from a nested table whose signature matches the table's project is a cinch.

Also, if the record actually matches an existing table we can declare the nested table with the %ROWTYPE syntax instead.

```
  1  declare
  2      type nt_emp temp_emp%rowtype;
  3      emp_recs nt_emp;
  4  begin
```

---

Bulk Collect and Forall are more efficient that the normal RBAR implementation but they are still sluggish compare to pure SQL.  So normally we would only use this sort of construct in we are undertaking some intermediate data manipulation on the array, which cannot itself be done in SQL.  As Oracle's SQL functionality increases with each release it becomes increasing rare to find such a need.

Answer (score 4):

You can use BULK COLLECT to fill an array (or at pl/sql table of records as such).
As Such:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  type xyz is record(colA number ,
                     colB Date) ;
  type xyz_table is table of xyz;

  p_xyz_table xyz_table ;

begin
    select level, sysdate+level 
           bulk collect into p_xyz_table
      from dual
      connect by level < 15 ;
      dbms_output.put_line('records=>' || p_xyz_table.count);
      FOR i IN  1 .. p_xyz_table.COUNT LOOP
          dbms_output.put_line(' colA=> ' || p_xyz_table(i).colA || '; colB=>' || p_xyz_table(i).colB);
      end loop ;
end ;
/

results:
records=>14
 colA=> 1; colB=>23/11/11 09:20:00
 colA=> 2; colB=>24/11/11 09:20:00
 colA=> 3; colB=>25/11/11 09:20:00
 colA=> 4; colB=>26/11/11 09:20:00
 colA=> 5; colB=>27/11/11 09:20:00
 colA=> 6; colB=>28/11/11 09:20:00
 colA=> 7; colB=>29/11/11 09:20:00
 colA=> 8; colB=>30/11/11 09:20:00
 colA=> 9; colB=>01/12/11 09:20:00
 colA=> 10; colB=>02/12/11 09:20:00
 colA=> 11; colB=>03/12/11 09:20:00
 colA=> 12; colB=>04/12/11 09:20:00
 colA=> 13; colB=>05/12/11 09:20:00
 colA=> 14; colB=>06/12/11 09:20:00
```

check out the documentation @ http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm , it has come in really handy for me in the past. (this will also answer your question about EXTEND)

If this isn't what you are looking for, please post a code snippet to help iron out the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Your solution worked 100%! Explained like you did, it all sounds clear to me! :D Regards, Pedro